# Map React JS : Displaying data with column

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

I'm using the map method in ReactJS, in the render.

```
<div>
{this.state.allFolders.map((folder)=>                                                                               
<p>{folder.name}</p>                                                                           
)}
</div>
```

So it works, but the problem results of displaying. 
[image]

I would want to have 4 items by column.. but I don't know how can I do this. I precise, I'm using Flexbox in CSS.

Thank you for your help

Comment: try Object.keys(this.state,allFolders).map instead, map is not a build in function to js-Objects

Comment: Do you use a CSS framework?

Comment: @physi I'm assuming `allFolders` is an array so he has access to `Array.prototype.map`?

Comment: But on topic: this question has nothing to do with react, it is a Css question and without any info about the css nobody can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your array into chunks before you process it to render.

say if you have an `array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` into 3 chunks `[ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8] ]`

**Manipulation**

```
this.state = {
  allFolders:[] //myarray initially in constructor
}
```

Process this array into chunks with splice as

```
chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var results = [];

    while (myArray.length) {
        results.push(myArray.splice(0, chunk_size));
    }

    return results;
}
```

You can now set your array into chunks, into componentWillMount() or in some other function that re-renders your component after putting it into state.

```
componentWillMount(){
  let allFolders = Object.assign([],this.state.allFolders);
  allFolders = chunkArray(allFolders,4); //creates a chunk of 4 arrays.
  this.setState({allFolders});
}
```

Render

```
{this.state.allFolders.map((item)=>  
    {item.map((folder)=>   //will run every chunk. i.e. 4 times in your case                                                                          
      <p>{folder.name}</p> 
    )}  
)}
```

P.S. However, It is better if you can use some `overflow-y:hidden` property of css with minimized efforts.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ROW AND COL from 'antd' or from 'bootstrap'
it will look like this 
//example

```
import {Row,Col} from 'antd'
```

//function to render the data

```
_renderData(){
    item.map((res, key)=>{
     <Col>
       <p>{res.name} </p>
     </Col>
   })
}
```

//in your jsx use this

```
<Row> {this_renderData()} </Row>
```